# Panda compare and remove data from csv and xls

Tags: python, csv, pandas, xls

I have 2 file (a .csv and a .xls).
The .csv have only one column (e-mail).
The .xls have many columns.
I try to compare email columns in these two files and remove from .xls mail address not in .csv.
The mails address are not sort.

I have write some code but I do not achieve my goal :

```
excel = pd.read_excel(file, skiprow=10, parse_cols = 'AL')
csv = pd.read_csv(namelist_file)
excel_keep = excel[excel.isin(csv)]
mask = excel.isin(csv.tolist())
excel[~mask]
print(excel_keep)
```

Have you an idea please ?
Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df_csv = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv)
df_xlsx = pd.read_excel(path_to_excel)

## assuming column header for email in both files is 'email'
## if not change it by df = df.rename(columns={'oldName': 'email'})

df_xlsx = df_xlsx[df_xlsx['email'].isin(df_csv['email'])]
```

hope that helps

Comment: Ok, that select only what I want thank you very much.

Comment: How can I remove all the rows which not contain email address from the csv ?

Comment: if they are null inside you can df=df[df['email'].isnull()==False], hope that helps, if problem solved pls mark right answer :)